# Simplest way to insert data into database with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

what is simples way to insert data into database using laravel framework

have this form:

```
<div class="border">
  {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'menu/profil', 'files' => true)) }}

    {{ Form::text('username') }}

    {{ Form::submit('submit') }}
  {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

and this

```
Route::post('menu/profil', function() {

        $username = Input::get('username');

        //code to insert username into database
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a Model for your table:

```
/* app/models/User.php */
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'my_users';
}
```

Second, insert data by instantiating your Model:

```
$user = new User;

$user->username = Input::get('username');

$user->save();
```

For more information check [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your user model setup...

```
User::create(array('username' => Input::get('username')));
```